# No Java Perspective in Eclipse 3.8

Tags: java, java-7

I'm unable to start a new java project in Eclipse. I'm running a Linux Mint virtual machine through my school, and downloaded Eclipse through the software manager. I also installed JDK7 and JDT.

Comment: if you go to Window > Open Perspective > Other...? Don't you see Java listed there?

Comment: File -> New... -> Other... -> Java Project?

Comment: My guess would be that the software manager only installed the skeleton of Eclipse without the java tools. Try to search for "eclipse" in the software manager or package manager and see if it offers you additional eclipse packages that relate to Java.

Comment: Eclipse 3.8 is _really_ old. Instead of downloading it via the software manager, go to [the website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and download an up-to-date version with proper Java tools installed, e.g. [this one](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars1). You just need to extract it, no installation needed.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. You're right, all I had to do was extract. Thank you so much!